# How to find dynamically created elements in drop-down list based on input entered using Webdriver and c#?

Tags: webdriver, c#

I'm trying to test a page that has an input but really its a drop down list. The user enters text and then a dropdown appears based on what the user inputted. They are groups that are in the database. If I look for these elements before typing anything they dont exist but once I start typing they do exist.  The problem is I cant just type the whole name and then press enter or return because an option has to be selected from the list.  I can press arrow down to get the focus on the item from the list but then if I say enter it doesnt select, it sends that enter to the original element and nothing gets selected.  I can find the select element:

```
var ddList = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ui-autocomplete-input"));
ddList.SendKeys("Admins");
```

This is the first time the list appears in the html.  It looks like this:

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
```

Comment: <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">  

Can't see this without editing the comment for some reason

Comment: Did you tried with Ajax control to click on the element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just type into the element like you said, and then find the elements?  You can just make an array of them, but I assume from what you said that if you type the whole name then just one will appear, so that should be easy enough.

//your code

```
Thread.Sleep(500); //may have to adjust this based on how long it takes to generate; you can also sleep the driver itself if you want

var elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".ui-menu-item")).ToArray();
var visible = elements.Where(r => r.Displayed).ToArray();
visible[0].Click();
```